# How to find the coodinates of a new bounding box from four circles present with known radius around the vertices of an existing bounding box

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geometry, latitude-longitude, extents

I have a bounding box which I have created. I know the lat lon of the four vertices of the box. On these vertices I have created a buffer circle of radius 10m and now I want to calculate a new bounding box which covers these four circles.

[image: Sample Image]

I have created four circles where I know the **lat,lon** of each points of the surface which makes the circle.

How can I create and find the coordinates of the 4 ends of this new rectangle/bounding box which encloses these four circles.

Comment: You probably have more than one problem here. First off, your map canvas is probably Web Mercator, for which planar measurement is unsupported (yes, it's in units of meters, but the poles are infinitely far from the Equator, so the distance accuracy varies from "wrong" to "awful" to "useless" the further you get from the Equator). The next issue is that there isn't a simple formula to add meters to geographic coordinates (it's a partial differential equation, only solvable through iterative means) -- there are function libraries to solve this, and you shouldn't roll your own.

Comment: What do you suggest to do ? This is for my bachelor thesis and I am stuck at this point. I want to create 4 circles of known radius on the edges of a bbox and then create a new bbox which encloses these 4 circles tightly.

Comment: Your box, in geodetic space, is NOT a box, it's a trapezoid. It's tiny, in geodetic terms, so you can choose to disregard this, but you should understand the complexities. This means research into the two Problems of Geodesy, so you understand the difference between Direct/Forward and Inverse/Reverse, and can use a Direct function to accomplish your task. You should also know how to choose an appropriate projection to solve this in planar space, and how to project back. Bonus points if you can quantify the difference. Go forth and research.

Comment: Thanks. I figured the way to do it.